# "Users resort to seeking..." -- Is it correct to use a gerund like this?

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

I am not sure if the use of a gerund is correct in the following sentence:

> Users resort to seekING answers in social media

or

> Users resort to seek answers in social media

I know that the rule is that if we can substitute the gerund with a noun then it's correct, otherwise I should use a verb. However, I'm not sure if using a noun would be correct. For instance:

> Users resort to **the search** *of* answers in social media

But in the above sentence I also added the word *of,* so should I add *of* after the gerund in the original sentence, i.e. "seeking of answers" or it is correct even without it?

Comment: Your first sentence is correct.

Comment: What do the examples given in [CED](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/resort-to-sth) indicate?

Comment: You are using the infinitive, not a gerund. Seeking is a good way to find. There is the gerund.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. @FumbleFingers I didn't know about "English Language Learners" site, thanks for pointing it out.